# Database for experimental diatomic ionization energies

Tags: molecules, reference-request, ionization-energy, databases

I am looking for a database, in which the **experimental** ionization energies (and e.g. heat of formation) of atoms and diatomic molecules are listed as files.
If it comes with a Python package, that would even better.

I found the [Pitt Quantum Repository](https://pqr.pitt.edu/), but there seem to be only theoretical values.

Comment: *CRC handbook of chemistry and physics* lists IEs of elements, atomic and several molecular ions. Also, have a look at [Resources for learning Chemistry](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/37303/resources-for-learning-chemistry).

Comment: Ah. The good old rubber bible. No chemistry shelf is complete without it. :-)

Answer (score 1):

NIST Atomic Spectra Database has the atom part. Not sure about molecules.
https://physics.nist.gov/PhysRefData/ASD/ionEnergy.html